# iText Update Table Data Dynamically in Multiple pages

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation

I am using iText 2.1.7 and due to client restriction we can not proceed with license version at least for now, with this version I am trying to create PDF which contain PDF and each page has summary of that Table data on each page, I am trying to do so but seems not possible, I tried to o through some article and as Table data is drawn first and in between is difficult to fetch data from particular page.

Steps :

1. Create Document
2. add PDF with say 100 record consider one column as integer
3. each page when it going to next page we have to calculate sum of that column so that each page has sum(Total) display
4. Currently I can see i have constant sum as Table Content is loaded initially first and then other events are fired based on new page creation.

Can anyone help me out with this issue? or have any suggestion how i can achieve it?

Thank You .

Comment: keep a pre defined number of records on one page and while showing bunch of records on page add another row to show summarized data

Comment: ok i think my question was not in correct form, I want to show Total in every page like you can say footer which contain total of particular column of table. in above approach is difficult to understand after which record i should stop and add new row with "total"

Comment: You should look into `PdfPTableEvent` and its extension interfaces in combination with a data model for your table. I haven't been working with pre-5 versions for quite a while now (actually even with pre-5.5 versions), so I'm not sure which events are available in 2.1.7 anymore.